# Connecting our website with Social networking sites

Tags: asp.net

How to connect our site with facebook and twitter websites and display tweets in home page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

both sites provide an api. It's pretty simple to display tweets using twitter's API or with http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/